# Identification of the intersection point of two lines

Tags: java, graphics, coordinate-systems

Here are the calculations

L1 = Line joining points A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2)
L2 = Line joining points c(x3,y3) and D(x4,y4)

**For Line L1**

Line Equation : y = m1*x + c1

slope m1 : (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

Y intercept : c1 = (y1 - m1*x1)

**For Line L2**

Line Equation : y = m2*x + c2

slope m2 : (y4-y3)/(x4-x3)

Y intercept : c2 = (y3 - m2*x3)

**For Point of Intersection**

Solving the above equations we get

x = (c2 -c1)/(m1-m2)

y = (c1*m2 - c2*m1)/(m2-m1)

These above calculations are used to calculate the intersection points in my java program.

**The Problem**

The problem occurs when the two lines are parallel to x-axis and y-axis respectively. For example if the connecting points are as follows

L1 = A(34,112) B(34,180)    ...(x-coordinate value remains constant)

L2 = C(72,100) D(88,100)    ...(y-coordinate value remains constant)

now m1 will become *Infinity* and m2 will become 0 accordingly c1 will become *Infinity* and c2=y3 as a result the computation of the intersection points using below given formula gives strange (NaN) result although the lines L1 and L2 must meet at (34,100).

x = (c2 -c1)/(m1-m2)

y = (c1*m2 - c2*m1)/(m2-m1)

Why such a problem ? How is this problem handled using math so that it can be implemented in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line which is parallel to the y-axis cannot be expressed as `y = ax + b`. You need to use the general equation of a line `ax + by + c = 0`. Determine the coefficients of the equations of your two lines and solve the linear system of their intersection. Make sure the determinant of the system is different from 0, otherwise there is no solution, or an infinity (which you can consider being another case of no solution).

You can obtain `a` and `b` coefficients quite easily considering the normal vector of your segment (if `vect(AB) = (x,y)` then `normal(AB) = (-y,x) = (a,b)`. You then determine `c` by introducing the coordinates of A in the equation : `c = -a*x_A - b*y_A`.

You now have a linear system to solve :

```
(S) : { a1*x + b1*y + c1 = 0    
      { a2*x + b2*y + c2 = 0
```

If `det = a1*b2 - a2*b1 = 0` (be careful with loss of precision, make your comparison epsilon-wise), then the system has no unic solution. Otherwise, you can find the inverse of the matrix of the system :

```
M = (a1  b1), M^(-1) = 1/det * ( b2  -b1) 
    (a2  b2)                   (-a2   a1)
```

Now you just need to compute

```
M^(-1) * (-c1) = 1/det * (-b2*c1 + b1*c2)
         (-c2)           ( a2*c1 - a1*c2)
```

And that's it, you have your solution !

Comment: do you mean that y=mx+c is not sufficient to define all straight lines. I am not a math major, i am a software professional but i never learnt this shortcoming of a straight line equation having slope.

Comment: It is only sufficient to describe all non-vertical lines. It is actually a different form of `ax + by + c = 0`. If `b` is not 0, you can divide by `b` and you have : `y = -a/b*x - c/b`. If `b` is 0, it is mathematically impossible to do it.

Comment: I gave every single step of the resolution, if you need me to highlight what is going to be actual code and what was only meant to show the mathematical reasonment, please tell me

Comment: I think the general equation of a straight line makes sense. And you determinant solution is elegent. Thanks

Comment: @Dici : nice to see some informaticians recalls their college math lessons :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta haha, I've actually had a good math/physics abstract education during what we call "classes préparatoires" in France before starting computer science and applied (more concrete) mathematics.